# Template structure specialization using typename ::

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, specialization, typename

I want to specialize struct B with a type which is defined inside another struct A.

One can see a MWE down in the post.

First I'm surprised the two specializations of B can exist together. I added the second one to show the problem. If removed, code see no proper specialization for B.
I'd prefer to only keep the first specialization.

So, my questions are :

- Why the two specializations of B can exist together ?
- Why the first one doesn't apply in main's instantiation ?

definitions.h :

```
template <class T>
class X {};

template <class T>
class Xitem {};


template <class T>
struct A;

template <class T>
struct A< X<T> > {
    typedef Xitem<T> Titem;
};

template <class T>
struct B;

template <class T>//I need this one only
struct B< typename A< X<T> >::Titem > {
    static void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo 1" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct B< Xitem<T> > {
    static void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo 2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

main.cpp :

```
#include "definitions.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    B< A< X<int> >::Titem >::foo();
}
```

Output : "foo 2"
Using Xcode 7

Comment: I'm guessing this is a violation of the one definition rule and the compiler just "picked one" to execute, but I'm not totally sure about that assessment.

Comment: The first one can never be used since `T` cannot be deduced. In more recent times, [that causes the program to be ill-formed](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.class.spec#match-3).

Comment: I think it doesn't take the first specialization because it can't resolve the type of T. gcc gave me an error message compiling your code: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization. If I explicitly name the type used in the template (int instead of T) it works, obviously not what you wanted though.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So, long story short, specializing a structure with "typename ::" (not sure how to call this) is not possible ? Provided there s a template involved

Comment: Imagine that you use, say, `B<int>`. You appear to expect the compiler to instantiate `A<X<T>>` for every possible type `T`, in the hopes that there might exist a specialization that happens to have a member `typedef int Titem` (or to prove that there is none such). Or else to engage in a theorem-proving exercise in order to prove that, with currently visible definitions and specializations of `A`, no possible `T` may result in `A< X<T> >::Titem` being an `int`. The compiler does not go to such lengths; it instead declares `T` to be non-deducible context, and never uses this specialization.

Comment: Makes sens, thanks. I guess C++ misses a "super" typename or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer given in comments by  Igor Tandetnik :

Imagine that you use, say, B. You appear to expect the compiler to instantiate A> for every possible type T, in the hopes that there might exist a specialization that happens to have a member typedef int Titem (or to prove that there is none such). Or else to engage in a theorem-proving exercise in order to prove that, with currently visible definitions and specializations of A, no possible T may result in A< X >::Titem being an int. The compiler does not go to such lengths; it instead declares T to be non-deducible context, and never uses this specialization.